# SSRS Report in CRM 4 IFrame not updating

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-4

I am using CRM 4 and have uploaded an ssrs report into the reports area. I published this for external use and in one of the entites have an iFrame that points to this published report.

This all works well, the problem is that if I update some of the info that the report is looking at and refresh the page the report doesn't update.

In fact I need to close the browser and re-open it of the report to refresh. This only happens in the iFrame, if I re-run the report in the reports section it updates correctly.

I assume this is because the info is cached somewhere. Does anybody know if there is a way to force CRM/SSRS to get the info afresh every time?

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an additional parameter to the end of the URL used as the IFRAME source

```
&rs:ClearSession=true
```

This forces a refresh of the report each time it is accessed.